How to read ios webview cookie before opening webviews?
When my users open my apps i display a webview to let them accept some legal stuff like cookies. When they accept that a cookie "consent:true" is created.
When users open later the app i tried to read cookies using WKWebsiteDataStore.default().httpCookieStore but result of getAllCookies is empty.
So I open again the webview but here I can well found my "consent" cookie...
Is it possible to read cookies before opening a webview instance ?
